# Building WALA (Watson Libraries for Analysis) with Maven fails

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a problem with building WALA using Maven. When I first built it, there where too many errors, so I solve a few errors. However, I still get the error below. How can I build the WALA?

```
[ERROR] Cannot resolve project dependencies:
[ERROR]   Software being installed: com.ibm.wala-repository raw:1.3.4.'SNAPSHOT'/format(n[.n=0;[.n=0;[-S]]]):1.3.4-SNAPSHOT
[ERROR]   Missing requirement: com.ibm.wala-feature.feature.group 1.3.4.v20150325-1754-b000 requires 'com.ibm.wala.cast [1.3.4.v20150325-1754-b000]' but it could not be found
[ERROR]   Cannot satisfy dependency: com.ibm.wala-repository raw:1.3.4.'SNAPSHOT'/format(n[.n=0;[.n=0;[-S]]]):1.3.4-SNAPSHOT depends on: com.ibm.wala-feature.feature.group 0.0.0
[ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.: [Unable to satisfy `dependency from com.ibm.wala-feature.feature.group 1.3.4.v20150325-1754-b000 to com.ibm.wala.cast [1.3.4.v20150325-1754-b000].;`1.3.4.v20150325-1754-b000 to com.ibm.wala.cast.source [1.3.4.v20150325-1754-b000].; Unable to satisfy dependency from `com.ibm.wala-feature.source.feature.`enter code here`group 1.3.4.v20150325-1754-b000 to com.ibm.wala.cast.java.source [1.3.4.v20150325-1754-b000].; `No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.] -> [Help 1]org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.: [Unable to satisfy dependency from com.ibm.wala-feature.feature.group 1.3.4.v20150325-1754-b000 to com.ibm.wala.cast [1.3.4.v20150325-1754-b000].; Unable to satisfy dependency from com.ibm.wala-feature.feature.group 1.3.4.v20150325-1754-b000 to com.ibm.wala.cast.java [1.3.4.v20150325-1754-b000].; Unable to satisfy dependency from com.ibm.wala-feature.source.feature.group 1.3.4.v20150325-1754-b000 to com.ibm.wala.cast.source [1.3.4.v20150325-1754-b000].; Unable to satisfy dependency from com.ibm.wala-feature.source.feature.group 1.3.4.v20150325-1754-b000 to com.ibm.wala.cast.java.source [1.3.4.v20150325-1754-b000].; No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.]`t org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:121)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)`Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No solution found because the problem isunsatisfiable.: [Unable to satisfy dependency from com.ibm.wala-feature.feature.group 1.3.4.v20150325-1754-b000 to com.ibm.wala.cast [1.3.4.v20150325-1754-b000].; Unable to satisfy dependency from com.ibm.wala-feature.feature.group 1.3.4.v20150325-1754-b000 to com.ibm.wala.cast.java [1.3.4.v20150325-1754-b000].; Unable to satisfy dependency from com.ibm.wala-feature.source.feature.group 1.3.4.v20150325-1754-b000 to com.ibm.wala.cast.source [1.3.4.v20150325-1754-b000].; Unable to satisfy dependency from com.ibm.wala-feature.source.feature.group 1.3.4.v20150325-1754-b000 to com.ibm.wala.cast.java.source [1.3.4.v20150325-1754-b000].; No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.]
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.AbstractResolutionStrategy.newResolutionException(AbstractResolutionStrategy.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.ProjectorResolutionStrategy.resolve(ProjectorResolutionStrategy.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.AbstractResolutionStrategy.resolve(AbstractResolutionStrategy.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.impl.resolver.P2ResolverImpl.resolveDependencies(P2ResolverImpl.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.impl.resolver.P2ResolverImpl.resolveDependencies(P2ResolverImpl.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2TargetPlatformResolver.doResolvePlatform(P2TargetPlatformResolver.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2TargetPlatformResolver.resolveDependencies(P2TargetPlatformResolver.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.resolver.DefaultTychoDependencyResolver.resolveProject(DefaultTychoDependencyResolver.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.maven.TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.afterProjectsRead(TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:266)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    ... 11 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/InternalErrorException

C:\Users\User\git\WALA>mvn clean -rf :com.ibm.wala.core.tests
```

Comment: Are you still having issues with this?

Answer (score 1):

The project you are trying to build has a circular dependency onto itself. You have to fix the project setup by figuring out which dependencies are wrong and should be changed.

The error message clearly says where the problem is. You just need to read it and check out where in the project source these dependencies are wrongly referenced.

Comment: Thank you :)
But I don't know. where is the wrong, and what should be changed.
Please Help ME....

Comment: I dont have the source code of that project nor the time check it out.